# Can I ask a question that does not have an answer here but is easily answered on google?

Tags: discussion, answers

I had a question.  I came here first to look for an answer.  There was no answer here.  I then went to google and found an answer.  I wondered if I should ask the question here and perhaps supply the answer myself (the one I found on google).  Can I, should I do that?  Maybe the difference is in being a passive or active user of stackexchange?  Not sure.

Comment: Please don't. Keep the knowledge to yourself.

Comment: This question happens 99.9% (overexageratting) of the time on Stack Overflow, so I wouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think asking such a question might be unwise because a common reason for downvoting is when a question is asked which has answer that could be easily found with the minimal research of a Google search.  You may also risk incurring downvotes on the self-answer to such a question.

The above notwithstanding, on most, if not all, sites it is fine to ask and self-answer questions, but they should be questions for which answers are not easy to find elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: I think the important part here is: "*easily* found". If an unambiguously correct answer is in the top few results on Google then don't ask, otherwise I (unlike many others) say it's a good idea to have the question. SE Q&As often *are* the top result on Google and that isn't a bad thing.